# Too many queries problem with JPA using Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing REST application using spring boot and I am trying to optimize the performance of the queries. I am currently using findById from the repositories which is causing performance issues. Code is given below:

User Entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"comments"})
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "first name should not be empty")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "last name should not be empty")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Email(message = "Not a valid email")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
//    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$",
//            message ="1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase, 1 special character, 1 number, Min 8 characters ")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "password should have at least 8 characters")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assignees")
    private Set<Issue> issues = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "voters")
    private Set<Issue> votedIssues = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members")
    private Set<Community> communities = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "requestingMembers")
    private Set<Community> requestedCommunities = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "admin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Community> communitiesCreated = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Issue Entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="issue")
public class Issue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate dateCreated;
    private boolean isOpen;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "issue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> voters = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> assignees = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "community_id")
    private Community community;

}
```

Comment Entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "issue_id")
    private Issue issue;

    private LocalDate dateCreated;
}
```

Role Enum

```
public enum Role {
    CUSTOMER("CUSTOMER"),
    EXPERT("EXPERT"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");

    private String role;

    Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return role;
    }
}
```

When I do a userRepository.findById(userId) there are so many select queries being fired. I am looking for a way to optimize the queries so that findById produces result in less queries. Currenlty it is making so many queries just for one api request for example :

```
2023-05-16T16:21:48.837+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from user u1_0 where u1_0.id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.911+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.assignees_id,i1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,i1_1.date_created,i1_1.description,i1_1.is_open,i1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_assignees i1_0 join issue i1_1 on i1_1.id=i1_0.issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=i1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_1.user_id where i1_0.assignees_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.921+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.927+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.930+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.assignees_id,i1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,i1_1.date_created,i1_1.description,i1_1.is_open,i1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_assignees i1_0 join issue i1_1 on i1_1.id=i1_0.issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=i1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_1.user_id where i1_0.assignees_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.932+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select v1_0.voters_id,v1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,v1_1.date_created,v1_1.description,v1_1.is_open,v1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_voters v1_0 join issue v1_1 on v1_1.id=v1_0.voted_issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=v1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=v1_1.user_id where v1_0.voters_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.933+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.members_id,c1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from community_members c1_0 join community c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_1.user_id where c1_0.members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.936+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.requesting_members_id,r1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from community_requesting_members r1_0 join community r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.requested_communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=r1_1.user_id where r1_0.requesting_members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.937+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from community c1_0 where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.938+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select m1_0.communities_id,m1_1.id,m1_1.email,m1_1.first_name,m1_1.last_name,m1_1.password,m1_1.role from community_members m1_0 join user m1_1 on m1_1.id=m1_0.members_id where m1_0.communities_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.938+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.940+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.941+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.assignees_id,i1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,i1_1.date_created,i1_1.description,i1_1.is_open,i1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_assignees i1_0 join issue i1_1 on i1_1.id=i1_0.issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=i1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_1.user_id where i1_0.assignees_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.942+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select v1_0.voters_id,v1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,v1_1.date_created,v1_1.description,v1_1.is_open,v1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_voters v1_0 join issue v1_1 on v1_1.id=v1_0.voted_issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=v1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=v1_1.user_id where v1_0.voters_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.943+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select v1_0.voters_id,v1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,v1_1.date_created,v1_1.description,v1_1.is_open,v1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_voters v1_0 join issue v1_1 on v1_1.id=v1_0.voted_issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=v1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=v1_1.user_id where v1_0.voters_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.944+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.members_id,c1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from community_members c1_0 join community c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_1.user_id where c1_0.members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.945+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select m1_0.communities_id,m1_1.id,m1_1.email,m1_1.first_name,m1_1.last_name,m1_1.password,m1_1.role from community_members m1_0 join user m1_1 on m1_1.id=m1_0.members_id where m1_0.communities_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.945+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from community c1_0 where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.946+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.community_id,i1_0.id,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue i1_0 left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where i1_0.community_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.947+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.requesting_members_id,r1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from community_requesting_members r1_0 join community r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.requested_communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=r1_1.user_id where r1_0.requesting_members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.947+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from community c1_0 where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.948+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.949+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.assignees_id,i1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,i1_1.date_created,i1_1.description,i1_1.is_open,i1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_assignees i1_0 join issue i1_1 on i1_1.id=i1_0.issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=i1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_1.user_id where i1_0.assignees_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.950+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select v1_0.voters_id,v1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,v1_1.date_created,v1_1.description,v1_1.is_open,v1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_voters v1_0 join issue v1_1 on v1_1.id=v1_0.voted_issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=v1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=v1_1.user_id where v1_0.voters_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.951+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.members_id,c1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from community_members c1_0 join community c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_1.user_id where c1_0.members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.951+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.requesting_members_id,r1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from community_requesting_members r1_0 join community r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.requested_communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=r1_1.user_id where r1_0.requesting_members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.952+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from community c1_0 where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.953+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.content,c1_0.date_created,i1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.user_id,c2_0.description,c2_0.name,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from comment c1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=c1_0.issue_id left join community c2_0 on c2_0.id=i1_0.community_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_0.user_id where c1_0.user_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.953+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.assignees_id,i1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,i1_1.date_created,i1_1.description,i1_1.is_open,i1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_assignees i1_0 join issue i1_1 on i1_1.id=i1_0.issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=i1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=i1_1.user_id where i1_0.assignees_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.954+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select v1_0.voters_id,v1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_0.description,c1_0.name,v1_1.date_created,v1_1.description,v1_1.is_open,v1_1.title,u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from issue_voters v1_0 join issue v1_1 on v1_1.id=v1_0.voted_issues_id left join community c1_0 on c1_0.id=v1_1.community_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.user_id left join user u1_0 on u1_0.id=v1_1.user_id where v1_0.voters_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.954+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.members_id,c1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,c1_1.description,c1_1.name from community_members c1_0 join community c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_1.user_id where c1_0.members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.955+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select r1_0.requesting_members_id,r1_1.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.email,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.password,a1_0.role,r1_1.description,r1_1.name from community_requesting_members r1_0 join community r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.requested_communities_id left join user a1_0 on a1_0.id=r1_1.user_id where r1_0.requesting_members_id=?
2023-05-16T16:21:48.955+05:30 DEBUG 63236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.user_id,c1_0.id,c1_0.description,c1_0.name from community c1_0 where c1_0.user_id=?
```

**I am expecting just one or two select queries.**

Comment: What queries does it fire ? Can you provide a bit more information ?

Comment: `userRepository.findById(userId)` should only execute 1 query - something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = userId`.

Comment: please update question with query logs.

Comment: `findById` isn't the problem, your mapping is the problem and the fact that you are using `Lombok`. Don't use Lombok with entities that only results in trouble. Write your own proper equals/hashcode method as well as toString. THe one generated by Lombok is wrong for JPA usage. I would suggest you start with that and see if it improves, how to write a proper equals/hashCode for JPA can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). If you want to use lombok only use `@Getter`/`@Setter` but not `@Data`.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please show the code that is using this (so the controller, service etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stop using `@Data` (or better Lombok all together) with JPA entities. When using `@Data` it will generate an `equals`/`hashCode`/`toString` method including all collections (which are lazy) in your entity. (I wrote [a blog](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/) about it about 4 years ago and yet we still haven't learned).

Those `hashCode` and `equals` method are important as those are used to determine if an object is already in the cache or not. Now to calculate the `hashCode` what do you think will happen.... Exactly queries, queries and some more queries.

I would suggest to create a `BaseEntity` which include a regular `hashCode`, `equals` and basic `toString` method. Then let all your entities extend this base class.

Next replace the `@Data` with only `@Getter`/`@Setter` to generate the getters/setters.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
public abstract BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
  }
  
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
 
    if (getClass().isInstance(o) && o instanceof BaseEntity other) {
      return this.id != null && Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s [id=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), this.id);
  }  
}
```

Now for example let your `Comment` class extend this and drop the usage of `@Data`.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment extends BaseEntity {

    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "issue_id")
    private Issue issue;

    private LocalDate dateCreated;
}
```

This should already reduce the number of queries that are being issued. Another optimization you could do is to use bytecode enhancements to lazy load the `Issue` in the `Comment` (the sample ofcourse applies to other fields that can be lazy loaded). But this requires bytecode enhancements.

Comment: I have made the changes that you showed me but it is still firing so many queries when I try issueRepository.findById(issueId). Logs are like 2023-05-17T22:21:00.421+05:30 DEBUG 72248 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select i1_0.id,i1_0.community_id,i1_0.date_created,i1_0.description,i1_0.is_open,i1_0.title,i1_0.user_id from issue i1_0
org.hibernate.SQL                       : select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password,u1_0.role from user u1_0 where u1_0.id=? so many more

Comment: Did you also include the `toString` and did it for all entities? Make sure you aren't logging the entities if you haven' overridden the `toString`. That being said if you are using this `User` directly in your controller it will serialize all the fields and thus lazy load all the other fields as well. Finally I would probably remove all the not needed collections from the user, or at least make them uni-directional (so remove them from the `User`) instead of bi-directional. Why would the user need to access the comments, issues etc. etc. directly, you can query them if needed!